# Can't install gensim with python 3.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gensim

I cannot install gensim==3.5.0 in my elastic beanstalk environment (python 3.4). I get an error that gensim needs python >= 3.5 to run.

This was not a problem until a mid-day deployment today, that made only project code changes, nothing related to elastic beanstalk, requirements or settings.

At the same time, I'm succesfully running the same version in another identical environment. That means the same pip, same python version, same required dependencies.

I tried lowering the gensim requirement to gensim==0.13.4 which officially supports python 3.4, but I get the same error.

EDIT: I managed to make things work by installing gensim==0.10.0 and then redeploying with gensim=3.5.0. I still don't know the cause of the issue and the solution is not really a solution, so I'm still interested in insights.

Answer (score 1):

Note that currently (July 2019), Python 3.4 itself will no longer be supported with fix releases. Per https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3410/:

> Release Date: March 18, 2019
>
> Python 3.4 has reached end-of-life. Python 3.4.10 is the final release
>   of 3.4.
>
> Python 3.4.10 was released on March 18th, 2019.
>
> Python 3.4.10 is the final release in the Python 3.4 series. As of
>   this release, the 3.4 branch has been retired, no further changes to
>   3.4 will be accepted, and no new releases will be made. This is standard Python policy; Python releases get five years of support and
>   are then retired.
>
> If you're still using Python 3.4, you should consider upgrading to the
>   current version. Newer versions of Python have many new features,
>   performance improvements, and bug fixes, which should all serve to
>   enhance your Python programming experience.

That said, if you're truly getting an error about `gensim`'s require Python level, truly rolling back to whatever version of `gensim` you were using successfully, previously, with Python 3.4 should work. (That might not need to go as far back as `gensim-0.13.4.1`, which is almost 2.5 years old, but if you're sure that's the version that was working for you, you could use that version.)

You should edit your question to show exactly what installation commands you've run, and exactly which message is received in response to which step, to more clearly indicate what's been tried, where the error is arising, and why a simple attempt to install-an-older-version might be getting a similar error message.

Comment: I'm not the OP, i just tried to install. `pip install --no-deps gensim==0.13.4` (and `gensim==0.13.3`) produce error "RuntimeError: Python >= 3.5 required."

Comment: Then it's likely that's always been the case for `gensim-0.13.4` and Python < 3.5 – the PyPI versions should not have been changed anytime since they were 1st available – and OP may have to go back even further to match what they had (presumably) previously successfully installed. But that the "just do the minimal to make it work like before" approach. It might be better for OP to do instead the "get off of no-longer-supported Python 3.4" approach.

Comment: Yep, I think so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer is not a solution. The version I was succesful previously is the last version of gensim==3.5.0

I managed to make things work by installing gensim==0.10.0 and then installing gensim==3.5.0, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: AWS still doesn't support higher versions of Python out of the box, so I'm hesitant to go that way

Comment: That may be a limitation of specific choices you've made – such as a specific older EC2 image – because the AWS docs I can find mostly reference later-than-Python-3.4, still-officially-supported versions of Python.